# can't see QVector<Qvector<whatever> > value in qtcreator 3.0 and gdb

Tags: windows, qt, gdb, qt-creator, qvector

i'm writting a qt application for homework and i need to debug it to solve a problem, but i have problems with gdb, when i try to see `QVector<double>` (for example) in locals and expressions, but when i try to read a `QVector<QVector<double> >` i get  message, i tried to change the display format but i didn't get lucky.
I'm using QT 5.2.1 for windows with Qtcreator 3.0
i have this sample code to fill a `QVector<QVector<double> >` to pass it to another class (which i need to debug)

```
for (int i = 1; i < npc.size(); i++) {
    capa = new QVector<QVector<double> >();
    for (int j = 0; j < npc[i]; j++) {
        pesos = new QVector<double>();
        for (int k = 0; k < npc[i-1]; k++) {
            pesos->append((double)1/(double)(k+1));
        }
        capa->append(*pesos);
    }
    nPesos.append(*capa);
}
```

in qt creator i can read every `pesos` instance but i cant read `capa` and i need it to solve my problem

EDIT: i tried @Nejat answer and i can read single `QVector<QVector<double> >` but not when it is inside a `QList` (so i can read every `capa` as separate but not `nPesos`)

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using pointers to QVector. There is no need to use pointers. You can simply use it like:

```
QVector<QVector<QVector<double> > > nPesos;
for (int i = 1; i < npc.size(); i++) {
    QVector<QVector<double> > capa;
    for (int j = 0; j < npc[i]; j++) {
         QVector<double> pesos;
        for (int k = 0; k < npc[i-1]; k++) {
            pesos.append((double)1/(double)(k+1));
        }
        capa.append(pesos);
    }
    nPesos.append(capa);
}
```

Comment: thanks! i forgot this because i was using java for many years and i;ve not programmed in c++ for more than one year... thanks it works

Comment: HELLO, i thought i was working but it doesnt work, i get the same result, <not accessible> QVector<QVector<double> >

Comment: edit: it works with a single QVector<QVector<double> > but not when it is inside a QList (QList<QVector<QVector<double> > >), for example i get QList with 4 elements but all elemets have the <not accessible> message